# Spatial grids over a shapefile or spatialpolygonsdataframe

Tags: raster, grids-graticules

I want to create a grid of 4 by 4km and then place it on a shapefile that I converted to a raster. The final product is a plot of my study area and my set of coordinates inside this created grids on the raster layer.

```
# create a grid of 4*4 km on map 
Nam <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = "Province_Data", layer="Namibia")
plot(Nam)

# create an empty raster
grid <- raster(extent(Nam))

# choose its resolution (4 by4 km)
res(grid) <- 4

# give the grid the projections
proj4string(grid) <- proj4string(Nam)

# transform this raster into a polygon and there is a grid now
gridpoly <- rasterToPolygons(grid)

#this rastertopolygon always gave me error saying r encountered fatal problem and needs to close and r needs to restart
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Please remember to indent all code by four spaces for proper formatting. You can use the `{}` button on the UI for this purpose.

Comment: It's likely that 4 is interpreted as *metres*, to be sure we need to see the `raster::projection(Nam)` - but if so the fix is simply `res(grid) <- 4000` rather than `res(grid) <- 4`.